# How can Arrays.asList return an instantiated List?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

`Arrays.asList` returns a typed List. But List is an interface so how can it be instantiated? If try and instantiated a typed List I get an error saying it is not possible.

**Edit**

Nevermind I see what's going on, just got confused by the docs for a moment.

Comment: Look at [the sourcecode](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an `Arrays.ArrayList` which shouldn't be confused with `java.util.ArrayList`. It is a wrapper for the array which means any changes you make, alter the original array, and you can't add or remove entries.  Often it is used in combination with ArrayList like

```
 List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "There", "World"));
```

Comment: The reference is to a List, but the object has to be a concrete class. That class happens to Arrays.ArrayList but the documentation suggests it could change in the future.

Comment: Yep, I just got confused by the docs for a moment, cheers anyway.

Comment: Hopefully I gave you more insight. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A `List` can't be instantiated, sure. But you can instantiate a class which *implements* `List` -- for example, an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, etc. These classes really are `List`s. The point of returning a `List` (the interface type) is that the method can return any object which implements the `List` interface, and you shouldn't worry about exactly which concrete type it is.

Answer (score 0):

from class Arrays

```
public static transient List asList(Object aobj[])
{
    return new ArrayList(aobj);
}
```

so when you execute Arrays.asList(...) you will take ArrayList which implements List. nobody will know that, except this one itself.

- 1  example

  String[] array  = new String[] {"one","two","three"};
  List list = Arrays.asList(array);